# webapp2 user store, how do you query it

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I'm using the webapp2 user store and I need to query User accounts. Where is that store located?

webapp2_extras.auth

something like

```
myusers = Users.query().filter(Users.somefield == somevalue).fetch()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? What "store"? Why do you need to know the location? What's wrong with that code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from webapp2_extras.appengine.auth.models import User
myusers = User.query().fetch()
```

Will fetch all users.